# CSS Grid container border doesn't scroll along

Tags: css, css-grid

```css
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 30px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    hyphens: auto;
  }

  .grid-container {
    height: 100vh;
    border: 10px solid #14a76c;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
      "header header header"
      "nav main ads"
      "footer footer footer";      
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
    grid-auto-rows: max-content;
    
  }

  .grid-item {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 4px solid #ff652f;
    /* padding: 20px; */
  }

  .item-1 {
    grid-area: header;
  }
  .item-2 {
    grid-area: nav;
  }
  .item-3 {
    grid-area: main;
  }
  .item-4 {
    grid-area: ads;
  }
  .item-5 {
    grid-area: footer;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>CSS Grid Tutorial</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item item-1">item 1</div>
    <div class="grid-item item-2">item 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item item-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus nemo minus itaque rem odit a in ducimus accusantium? Architecto dolorum debitis nihil aliquam, explicabo aspernatur nostrum voluptate, sunt deserunt saepe tempore similique beatae quo iste quisquam eum alias quibusdam aut vitae. Quis, labore aspernatur ipsa tenetur voluptatibus earum cupiditate nihil odit nesciunt illo repellendus id ex eius dolor enim incidunt fugit, voluptate soluta iure placeat repellat error eos. Laboriosam, laudantium. Minima cum dolorem architecto perspiciatis dignissimos nihil exercitationem accusantium id nulla, hic, eos sed? Ipsam natus, ullam quasi harum laudantium quae mollitia omnis aspernatur quo voluptatem rerum aliquid id maiores impedit soluta! Fugit excepturi facilis nesciunt nobis, ab reiciendis, voluptates et quaerat qui nulla voluptate dolorum ipsum quo, officia earum assumenda. Delectus, deleniti porro sunt corporis maiores voluptates nulla harum omnis libero autem qui. Deserunt fugiat perspiciatis, quia quisquam, voluptates atque natus sint velit praesentium vitae unde voluptas nisi fugit dicta suscipit enim accusamus. Maxime pariatur consequatur repellat enim quidem esse, illo, distinctio facere et eius voluptatibus beatae libero, praesentium magnam accusantium omnis numquam! Sed sunt vero ut ad aperiam repellat accusamus quo sint hic quod debitis sequi temporibus autem beatae adipisci aliquid, officiis, a laborum quam tempora ex delectus.</div>
    <div class="grid-item item-4">item 4</div>
    <div class="grid-item item-5">item 5</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So I find that the grid container's border adapts to window resizing just fine.

[window resize extends the border as I go](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbhdR.png)

My issue is when the content is too big for one screenful, and I scroll down to see the rest of it, the border stops at the 100vh mark and doesn't extend as I scroll down. It's giving the impression that border-bottom was overlapped by the contents.

[no border-bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpewT.png)

I wanted my container to wrap around the children and grow/shrink to wrap its contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `height: 100vh;` to `height: 100%;` in `.grid-container`

```css
 * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 30px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    hyphens: auto;
  }

  .grid-container {
    height: 100%;
      border: 10px solid #14a76c;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
      "header header header"
      "nav main ads"
      "footer footer footer";      
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
    grid-auto-rows: max-content;
    
  }
  


  .grid-item {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 4px solid #ff652f;
    /* padding: 20px; */
  }

  .item-1 {
    grid-area: header;
  }
  .item-2 {
    grid-area: nav;
  }
  .item-3 {
    grid-area: main;
  }
  .item-4 {
    grid-area: ads;
  }
  .item-5 {
    grid-area: footer;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>CSS Grid Tutorial</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item item-1">item 1</div>
    <div class="grid-item item-2">item 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item item-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus nemo minus itaque rem odit a in ducimus accusantium? Architecto dolorum debitis nihil aliquam, explicabo aspernatur nostrum voluptate, sunt deserunt saepe tempore similique beatae quo iste quisquam eum alias quibusdam aut vitae. Quis, labore aspernatur ipsa tenetur voluptatibus earum cupiditate nihil odit nesciunt illo repellendus id ex eius dolor enim incidunt fugit, voluptate soluta iure placeat repellat error eos. Laboriosam, laudantium. Minima cum dolorem architecto perspiciatis dignissimos nihil exercitationem accusantium id nulla, hic, eos sed? Ipsam natus, ullam quasi harum laudantium quae mollitia omnis aspernatur quo voluptatem rerum aliquid id maiores impedit soluta! Fugit excepturi facilis nesciunt nobis, ab reiciendis, voluptates et quaerat qui nulla voluptate dolorum ipsum quo, officia earum assumenda. Delectus, deleniti porro sunt corporis maiores voluptates nulla harum omnis libero autem qui. Deserunt fugiat perspiciatis, quia quisquam, voluptates atque natus sint velit praesentium vitae unde voluptas nisi fugit dicta suscipit enim accusamus. Maxime pariatur consequatur repellat enim quidem esse, illo, distinctio facere et eius voluptatibus beatae libero, praesentium magnam accusantium omnis numquam! Sed sunt vero ut ad aperiam repellat accusamus quo sint hic quod debitis sequi temporibus autem beatae adipisci aliquid, officiis, a laborum quam tempora ex delectus.</div>
    <div class="grid-item item-4">item 4</div>
    <div class="grid-item item-5">item 5</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Or keep the `height: 100vh;` and add `overflow-y: scroll;` if the above isnt what you're looking for.

See here:

```css
 * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 30px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    hyphens: auto;
  }

  .grid-container {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
      border: 10px solid #14a76c;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
      "header header header"
      "nav main ads"
      "footer footer footer";      
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
    grid-auto-rows: max-content;
    
  }
  


  .grid-item {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 4px solid #ff652f;
    /* padding: 20px; */
  }

  .item-1 {
    grid-area: header;
  }
  .item-2 {
    grid-area: nav;
  }
  .item-3 {
    grid-area: main;
  }
  .item-4 {
    grid-area: ads;
  }
  .item-5 {
    grid-area: footer;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>CSS Grid Tutorial</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item item-1">item 1</div>
    <div class="grid-item item-2">item 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item item-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus nemo minus itaque rem odit a in ducimus accusantium? Architecto dolorum debitis nihil aliquam, explicabo aspernatur nostrum voluptate, sunt deserunt saepe tempore similique beatae quo iste quisquam eum alias quibusdam aut vitae. Quis, labore aspernatur ipsa tenetur voluptatibus earum cupiditate nihil odit nesciunt illo repellendus id ex eius dolor enim incidunt fugit, voluptate soluta iure placeat repellat error eos. Laboriosam, laudantium. Minima cum dolorem architecto perspiciatis dignissimos nihil exercitationem accusantium id nulla, hic, eos sed? Ipsam natus, ullam quasi harum laudantium quae mollitia omnis aspernatur quo voluptatem rerum aliquid id maiores impedit soluta! Fugit excepturi facilis nesciunt nobis, ab reiciendis, voluptates et quaerat qui nulla voluptate dolorum ipsum quo, officia earum assumenda. Delectus, deleniti porro sunt corporis maiores voluptates nulla harum omnis libero autem qui. Deserunt fugiat perspiciatis, quia quisquam, voluptates atque natus sint velit praesentium vitae unde voluptas nisi fugit dicta suscipit enim accusamus. Maxime pariatur consequatur repellat enim quidem esse, illo, distinctio facere et eius voluptatibus beatae libero, praesentium magnam accusantium omnis numquam! Sed sunt vero ut ad aperiam repellat accusamus quo sint hic quod debitis sequi temporibus autem beatae adipisci aliquid, officiis, a laborum quam tempora ex delectus.</div>
    <div class="grid-item item-4">item 4</div>
    <div class="grid-item item-5">item 5</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks. I'm not sure how I missed that. silly me.

Comment: changing 100vh to 100% is simply removing the 100vh because 100% will do nothing here since the parent element has no defined height